# column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause, not sure what's the problem

Tags: sql

Write a SELECT statement that returns three columns:  Date,  closing price for IBM
Ticker, and closing price for GLD ticker. Don't understand why I get this error..."Column 'TS_DailyData.Close' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

```
SELECT Date, [Close] AS IBM_Close, [Close] AS GLD_Close
FROM Table
WHERE Ticker = 'IBM'
UNION
SELECT Date, [Close] AS IBM_Close, [Close] AS GLD_Close
FROM Table
WHERE Ticker = 'GLD';
```

also tried this

```
SELECT Date, [Close] AS IBM_Close, [Close] AS GLD_Close
FROM TS_DailyData
WHERE Ticker = 'IBM'
GROUP BY Date
UNION
SELECT Date, [Close] AS IBM_Close, [Close] AS GLD_Close
FROM TS_DailyData
WHERE Ticker = 'GLD'
GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: `FROM Table` is not valid SQL.  I suggest posting the real code.  Also, please tag SQL Server if you are using that database.

Comment: Add table structure and sample data. Otherwise can not help you.